# What is tsql 'sys.sp_addmessage' alternative for azure sql databases?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to add a custom exception error message number in tsql SP as this:

```
sys.sp_addmessage
    @msgnum = 54321,
    @severity = 18,
    @msgtext='My custom message comes here.',
    @replace = 'REPLACE'
```

It works fine in my localhost, but when trying to execute SP on azure SQL database I'm getting this error:

`Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 9 Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_addmessage`

After I researched, found out that sys.sp_addmessage is not supported for Azure Sql database. Someone, please suggest a workaround...

Comment: Start using `THROW`, then you don't need to add the message into `sys.messages`. This is even suggested in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi @YotkoKanchev, If the answer is helpful for you ,please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with @Larnu:

- Start using `THROW`, then you don't need to add the message into
  `sys.messages`. This is even suggested in the documentation:[RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

RAISERROR (Transact-SQL) is supported in Azure SQL database:

- Generates an error message and initiates error processing for the
  session. RAISERROR can either reference a user-defined message stored
  in the sys.messages catalog view or build a message dynamically. The
  message is returned as a server error message to the calling
  application or to an associated CATCH block of a TRY...CATCH
  construct. New applications should use [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.

These maybe what you're finding.